# perl jump to specific line in loop

Tags: perl, loops, hash

I have Logfile structure like this:

> ```
> Start Sollumsatz-Verrechnung 05.12.2018 03:42:51  
> Verwende 20 Threads.
> Anzahl gesamt     : 162360
> Anzahl erfolgreich: 162360
> Anzahl fehlerhaft : 0
> Ende Sollumsatz-Verrechnung 05.12.2018 04:03:03
> ```

I want to save some of the information in an hash (%hash_ref). In the "flag-part" my code jumps to the line "Verwende 20 Threads." but it should jump to "Anzahl erfolgreich". Do you know how this can be done?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
my %hash_ref;
my %filter;
my ($act, $time,$flag);
while(my $line = <FILE>) {
    if ($line =~ /(.+? Sollumsatz-Verrechnung)\s+(\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/) {
            ($act,$time) = ($1,$2);
            $flag = 1;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /(.+? Deaktiviere PKonten)\s+(\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/) {
            ($act,$time) = ($1,$2);
            $flag = 1;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /(.+? PSK historisieren)\s+(\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/) {
            ($act,$time) = ($1,$2);
            $flag = 1;
    }
    else {
                    if ($flag) {
                            print $line,"\n" # this outputs 'Verwende 20 Threads'
                            if ($line =~ /Anzahl erfolgreich:\s+(.+?)\s*$/) {
                                    #print $line, "\n";
                                    push @{ $hash_ref{$act}{'Anzahl'} }, $1;
                            }
                    }
                    $flag = 0;
    }
    if (! defined($filter{$act}{$time})) {
            push @{ $hash_ref{$act}{'time'} }, $time;
            $filter{$act}{$time} = 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see where the "Verwende 20 Threads" part of your code is.

Comment: @lurker: when you insert 'print $line,"\n";' after 'if ($flag)' it will output 'Verwende 20 Threads'

Comment: Hint: use your own pattern recognition to reduce possible problems.: `my $neodate = qr{\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d};` and use `$neodate` from there on.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue actually by this:

```
else {
       next if $line !~ /Anzahl erfolgreich/;
       if ($flag) {
```

Comment: I would suggest that `next if !~` might be better written as `next unless $line =~ ....`